# How to increase memory size to the heap of java

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I want to increase heap java to avoid this error message
I have windows 7 64bit with java version

```
C:\Users\Rasha>java -version
java version "1.5.0_15"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_15-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_15-b04, mixed mode)

java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Although I have already 6 Gigabyte memory, how to made the system to recognize them?

any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Use the 64 bit JVM. The 32 bit JVM cannot allocate much beyond 1.5 gb (eg right about where you are having difficulties) due to need for contiguous address space. I KNOW you are using the 32 bit JVM because it says "Client VM" above, and there is no "Client VM" for 64 bit.

Comment: how much will the 64 bit version use/be able to see?  An equation would be great.

Comment: The 64-bit version is limited by the OS. This can be between 8 GB and 256 TB.

Comment: True, but irrelevant (mostly) to the core of his question

Comment: @PeterLawrey How can you see / adjust what that value is?

Comment: The maximum memory limited by the OS is adjusted by using a different OS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#Memory

Comment: So the entire system RAM minus the OS is what gets used by the JVM. Awesome, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, I found the problem, I have multi version of java which conflicts the configuration
the solution is to remove all versions and install the java 64 bit version and the space is allocated  well
thank you every body